# Wordpress custom new-post interface

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a plugin where I need to show a new post interface in the multisite network management context, and I'm facing some problems replicating the new-post.php flow in the a plugin context.

Any ideas in how to proceed? what hooks to use to replicate the WP_Screen state? Any plugins with similar functionality that I could look into?

Comment: Means you want to add custom post type like default post working ( add post,all post etc ) ?

Comment: The main idea is to use the interface in the network management to post in multiple blogs